# Solving a PDE in the form $u_{xx} - au_{tx} + bu_{tt} = 0$ with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

This equation has the following initial conditions:

- $u(0,x) = p(x)$
- $u_t(0,x) = q(x)$

---

**This is my working so far:**

The question assumes we can factor it like so:

$(u_x - cu_t)(u_x - du_t)u = 0$  (where $cd = b$ and $-c-d = a$)

Then, I find the general solution of $(u_x + cu_t)$ and $(u_x + du_t)$ which are:
$f(cx + t)$ and $g(dx +t)$ respectively. Thus:

$u(t,x) = f(cx+t) + g(dx+t)$

To satisfy the initial data, we need:

1. $u(0,x) = f(cx) + g(dx) = p(x)$
2. $u_t(0,x) = f'(cx) + g'(cx) = q(x)$

Integrating 2. gives us:

3. $[1/c * f(cx)] + [1/d * g(dx)] = $$\int p(x) \, dx $

---

This is my roadblock. My textbook states that the RHS of 3. should, in fact, be:

$\int p(x') \, dx' $

Why is this the case? And how should I proceed from here? Will my final answer be in the form of $x'$ or is there a way to find the derivative of $x$?

Comment: the primes aren't derivatives.  The textbook is being pedantic that you shouldn't use a variable with another meaning as your integration variable.

Comment: OH. I hadn't thought of that! thanks for the clarification